# Algebraic varieties being geometrically irreducible

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, field-theory

I have trouble comprehending the so-called notion of being geometrically irreducible. More specific, I was doing an exercise in Hartshorne, *Algebraic Geometry*, First Properties of Schemes, exercise $3.15$.

Briefly, let $k$ be a field and $X$ a scheme over $k$. Then $X$ is said to be *geometrically irreducible* if $X_{k'} = X \times_{k} k'$ (by the abuse of notation, I write $k$ to mean $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$). The exercise asks readers to show that the following three conditions are equivalent provided $X$ is a scheme of finite type over $k$:

- $X \times_k \overline{k}$ is irreducible, where $\overline{k}$ is the algebraic closure of $k$.
- $X \times_k k^{sep}$ is irreducible, where $k^{sep}$ is the separable closure of $k$.
- $X$ is geometrically irreducible.

Note that the third implies the first one trivially, the first one implies the second because the property of being surjective is preserved under base change.

The solutions which are available online seem to be so terse and vague, therefore I have had to search for several sources, including Vakil's note *FOA* (section $9.5$) and QingLiu, *Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves* (section $3.2.2$). The two core lemmas in QingLiu are

> *Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $k$, $K/k$ an algebraic extension of fields. Then for every reduced closed subvariety $W$ of $X \times_k K$, there exists a finite subextension $K'/k$ of $K/k$, and a unique reduced closed subvariety $Z$ of $X \times_k K'$ such that $W = Z \times_k K$.*

> Let $X$ be an algebraic variety over $k$, $K/k$ an algebraic extension. If $K/k$ is purely inseparable, then the projection $X \times_k K \to X$ is a homeomorphism.

I understand their proofs, but can not deduce the general case (an arbitrary extension $K/k$ instead of just being purely inseparable or algebraic). I think my problem is I do not truly understand the roles of two extensions $\overline{k}/k,k^{sep}/k$ here. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: You might find my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3654825/base-change-and-irreducibility-reducedness-connectedness-in-qing-lius-book-3-2/3659052#3659052) useful if you're after solutions using those two statements from Liu's book. If you're interested in other solutions (are you?), I think there are better ways to go. (One point worth noting: Hartshorne allows arbitrary extensions while Liu only considers algebraic extensions, so the proofs have an extra step.)

Comment: @KReiser, I hope you could give me a hint for the 'extra step'.

Comment: It's more or less what Mindlack posted - for an arbitrary extension $k\subset K$, you can consider the two towers of extensions $k\subset K\subset\overline{K}$ and $k\subset\overline{k}\subset\overline{K}$. Now you're only on the hook for showing the claim for an algebraic extension and an extension where the smaller field is algebraically closed: if you know these facts, then $X_{\overline{K}}$ is irreducible and surjects on to $X_K$. The second fact can be seen as an extension of the nullstellensatz in a nice way: see Eric's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2753223/).

Comment: @KReiser, I wonder whether $X$ is an algebraic variety (as in Liu's) is neccessary?

Comment: The least restrictive version of this that I know is that you can prove this result for a scheme over a field (no finite type hypothesis). This is done in the Stacks Project section you've linked to in the comments on the answer, for instance.

Comment: @KReiser, I think the first statement (which is lemma $2.6$ Liu), the hypothesis $X$ is an algebraic variety is important, at the second line in its proof, Liu says a radical ideal $I$ of $A_K$ is finitely generated. This definitely fail if $A$ is not f.g $k$-algebra as the tensor product of two $k$-algebra is noetherian provided one is noetherian and the other one is f.g $k$-algebra. Perhaps stackproject used different tools.

Comment: Yes, they do use different tools, as you can read on the Stacks Project. The comments to this post are not really the right place to get in to the different methods of proof. Good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, it's an important fact in itself that $X_{\overline{k}} \rightarrow X_{k^{sep}}$ is a *homeomorphism*.

To do that, it's not an issue to reduce to the case of affine $X$, and thus you want to show that for any $k$-algebra $A$, we have a natural correspondance between the spectra of $A \otimes \overline{k}$ and $A \otimes k^{sep}$. To do that, the main ingredient is to note that for each $x \in A \otimes \overline{k}$, in prime characteristic $p > 0$, there is an integer $n \geq 0$ such that $x^{p^n} \in A \otimes k^{sep}$. (It's not *entirely* obvious how to go on after that, but it's not very difficult).

Now, we want to explain why, if $X_{\overline{k}}$ is irreducible, then for any extension $k'/k$, $X_{k'}$ is irreducible.

First, we can assume $k$ is algebraically closed. Indeed, let $K$ be an algebraic closure of $k'$, so that we have a map $\overline{k} \rightarrow K$ (respecting $k' \cap \overline{k}$). Now $K/\overline{k}$ is a field extension, and $X_{\overline{k}}$ is irreducible. If $X_K$ is indeed irreducible, then, as $X_K \rightarrow X_{k'}$ is surjective, it follows that $X_{k'}$ will be irreducible.

So assume that $k$ is an algebraically closed field and $X$ is an irreducible scheme over $k$. Let $K/k$ be a field extension, we want to show that $X_{K}$ is irreducible. It's enough to show it when $X$ is affine (because the affine subsets of a general irreducible $X$ are dense and irreducible, and their base changes will be irreducible, and will pairwise intersect, which forces $X_K$ to be irreducible by topology), and we can furthermore assume $X$ is reduced (so $X$ is the spectrum of an integral $k$-algebra $A$), and we will show that if $K/k$ is an extension, $A\otimes K$ is an integral domain.

Let $K/k$ be an extension and let $a,b \in A \otimes K$ have a null product. There is a finitely generated (and integral) $k$-subalgebra $B \subset K$ such that $a,b$ are in the image of the monomorphism (flatness) $A \otimes_k B \rightarrow A \otimes K$, so we want to show that, in $A \otimes B$, $a$ or $b$ must be zero when their product is zero.

Now, take a $k$-basis $e_i$ of $A$, and let $a_i,b_i$ be the coordinates of $a,b$ in the $B$-basis $e_i \otimes 1$. Then, $(a_i)_i,(b_i)_i$ are almost null sequences of elements of $B$. Assume that there are some nonzero $a_i,b_j$. Then $a_ib_j \in B$ is nonzero (and $B$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra), hence is *not* contained in some maximal ideal $\mu$ by the Nullstellensatz. Consider the reduction map mod $\mu$: $A \otimes B \rightarrow A$ (as $k$ is algebraically closed): then the images of neither $a$ nor $b$ are zero, but their product is, so $A$ isn't an integral domain, so we have a contradiction, which shows that $A \otimes K$ is a domain and we are done.

Comment: The first two paragraphs are fine, the first line follows from the second statement in the post and the fact $x^q \in A \otimes k^{sep}$ is obtained by the fact that for every polynomial $p(x)$, there exists a largest integer $e$ and another $p_1$ such that $p(x)=p_1(x^{p^e})$. Btw, this is an excellent! I have not meticulously checked details but it seems to be true; thank you, I will comment here if I have any further question.

Comment: @Bang Pham Khoa: Thank you! Btw, these kinds of statements are bound to be in the Stacks Project, so that’s a useful (free online) reference to check if you’re stuck on anything else later on.

Comment: I was reading https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0364 about geometrically irreducible schemes, it makes me want to jump out of window.

Comment: @Bang Pham Khoa: I can definitely understand that urge (while suggesting that you do not yield). But actually their proof is very elegant too: the core fact is to show that if $A,B$ are finitely generated intgral domains over an algebraically closed field $k$, then $A \otimes B$ is a domain too. Let $X,Y,Z$ be the spaces of $k$-points of the spectra of $A,B, A \otimes B$. Then $Z \rightarrow Y$ is open (by algebra) and with irreducible fibers and image (by the hypotheses). So if $U,V \subset Z$ are open subsets that don’t meet, so must be the images of $U$ and $V$ in $Y$, a contradiction.

Comment: It seems that you do not need the hypothesis of $A$ being finitely generated $k$-algebra? (I have just added it, according to Hart's book)

Comment: I see, no f.g hypothesis is needed, a 'similar' proof could be found in S.Iataka, Algebraic Geometry and Birational Geometry, lemma 1.54.